# iOS dropping Tasks in the middle of execution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, async-await, xamarin.forms

Something is dropping my running tasks beyond a certain point in the code(see where below). It just stops executing. It only happens on iOS devices. On iOS simulators and android devices it runs perfectly. Anyone seen anything like this before? I don't think it's deadlocks or race conditons, because then it wouldn't complete successfully on other devices right?

Here's some code;

```
private async Task ExecuteFreshAndPopulateUI(IFetchVehicleCommand command)
{
    List<Models.Vehicle.Vehicle> vehicles = await command.ReturnAndExecute<Models.Vehicle.Vehicle>();
    var z = 9;
    ListPopulateObservableCollection(vehicles, view.Vehicles);
}

public virtual async Task<dynamic> ReturnAndExecute<T>() where T : new()
{
    await FlushCache<T>();
    await Execute();
    await CheckIfCached<T>();
    return (dynamic) cachedResult.cachedObject;
}

public override async Task Execute()
{
    try
    {
        dynamic x = await fetchableService.Fetch(userId);
        if (x != null)
        {
            await cacheProvider.Cache(x); // THIS is the last line to be called from this method, it never returns
            SetCached(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AddValidationError(ex.Message);
    }
}

public async Task Cache(dynamic obj)
{
    await database.InsertAllAsync((IEnumerable)obj); // this runs
} // this is the last breakpoint to be hit
```

Edit: reduced the code to make the issue clearer.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a try-catch block? async tasks don't bubble the exceptions out of them, so when an exeption is thrown, nothing fails. That might be it!

Comment: It's wrapped inside a try/catch in the Execute method, won't that catch them? Anyways it get's cached successfully(if I try to load the page again it get's from cache and that works)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you stand right now... And I can't see where `Execute` is called! Is it in `ExecuteIfValid`?

Comment: @MagnusBraathen: Reduce to the minimum code that reproduces the problem, and then it might become obvious. Or might not. :)

Comment: @PhilippeParé you're exactly right!

Comment: Based on the other comments here, I suspect a problem with the task generation in `database.InsertAllAsync()`. Can you share that part of the code?

Comment: @KeithRome it's just an async connection to https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Comment: Also, as mentioned in one of the answer submissions - you should *never* use DLR features in iOS code, as there are many dragons there. The `dynamic` keyword will cause the compiler to inject Call Sites, and I don't think those are implemented fully. And if they are, they incur a lot of overhead. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just cache your items as System.Object and re-cast them more strongly when retrieving them.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that call to SQLite with try/catch to see if an exception is coming back there?

Comment: @KeithRome Holy shit, thank you so much, replacing dynamic with object did it! I have to add a lot of tedious casts now but I can't belive it's been laying there infront of me the entire time. I've read that post so many times but it never concluded that dynamic couldn't be used. Post it as answer and I'll mark it!

Comment: Also I did try wrapping it, nothing gave.

Comment: The answer you've already marked is close enough. It doesn't explain "why" as clearly, but it ultimately is saying the same thing.

Comment: By the way, in general you should avoid `dynamic`, even when writing code on server or desktop platform apps. This keyword triggers a lot of hidden things in the framework that can cause some very unexpected behavior. The only time I've found it truly necessary is when duck-typing to `IDynamicObjectProvider` objects such as when hosting the DLR scripting engine.

Comment: @KeithRome If you do not plan on creating your own answer, do you mind if I include your comment's info in the answer to make it more complete?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I actually wrote a lengthy blog post about this subject about 5 years ago when I was involved with a major DLR implementation: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/krome/dynamic-objects-and-call-sites feel free to pull in any relevant details. The main thing is that using `dynamic` causes the compiler to emit Call Sites, when in turn require `DynamicMethod`, and that relies on creation of bytecode at runtime (not allowed in iOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with iOS devices' known limitation in terms of dynamic support. Xamarin's info on this [here](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation) and a thread [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3974/is-code-using-dynamic-objects-supported-in-xamarin-ios) (but as you can see from the last post in the thread, some dynamic support may be available).

The tricky thing about this is that the dynamic code would work fine on an iOS simulator (since Macs support JIT) but would fail on an iOS device (since the iOS device hardware has it specifically disabled).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about that! I think I read somewhere that as long as it's able to figure it out at compile time, it will be ok using dynamics.

Comment: As far as my testing have gone all the dynamics are fine, the core of the problem is that if I await the cacheProivder.Cache call it never returns to the calling method even when it completes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution. Removing the await from 
    await cacheProvider.Cache(x); 
inside the Execute method made it return back to the Execute method and the operation was able to complete successfully. It's partial because it only works in debugging, when I run it through our CI in adhoc config it still doesn't complete.